# Bordered table: weird last row?

Tags: tables

I am trying to make a simple table in LaTeX following some tutorials but I am getting an extra column/row after the last row? Why is this? Any help would be highly appreciated :)

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}
\maketitle


\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c |} \hline
Date & Reasons for review & Changes & Version \\ \hline
yy/xx/2012 & First edition & - & 1.0 \\ \hline
yy/xx/2012 & Something added & Section 5 & 1.01 \\ \hline
￼￼￼￼yy/xx/2012 & More things & Section n & 1.02 \\ \hline
￼￼\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You've got some extra white space in the *last* row.  Remove the white space in front of `\end{tabular}` and you'll be set.

Comment: Thanks! Could you put this as an answer? :) So I can put the check mark

Comment: How does one end up with [OBJECT REPLACEMENT CHARACTER](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffc/index.htm) in their source? (It’s twice in front of `\end{tabular}` and four times in front of the actual last row.)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel, how'd you figure out what that character was?  I only knew it wasn't ascii.

Comment: @A.Ellett copy/paste worked for me :)

Comment: @A.Ellett Copy/paste to my editor (that can’t really deal UTF8 characters in a good way (placement of characters get messed up)), copy/paste to the [above-linked site](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm), copy/paste Notepad++ (can deal better with UTF8) and its plugin HEX-Editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got some kind of *foreign* white space in the last row---probably some non-ascii character that's showing up as white space---which is making LaTeX think there is a new row.  Eliminate it and your table should look like what you want.